# Magnolia CMS doesn't logout

Tags: magnolia

I'm working on my inherit Magnolia CMS project and I have strange problem. 
When I try to logout

[image]

My session is not terminated and I'm redirected to a different page:

*www.my-web-page.com/author?mgnlLogout=true*

Not to the admin central login page.

*www.my-web-page.com/author/.magnolia/admincentral*

When I go to *www.my-web-page.com/author/.magnolia/admincentral*

I'm logged in, not logged out.

Do you know how and from where I can configure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/author` is your context, so when you point to that url alone, there's most likely redirect first and the logout parameter is lost during redirect and not transferred to Magnolia. Try to point to the same URL as you have for admincentral w/ the logout parameter.
BTW AdminCentral should be doing that for you automatically ... unless you have configured some virtual mapping that prevents that URL or request param from reaching the instance.